# converting nested loop to list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, list-comprehension

I am writing a program that defines two functions called `Funct()` and `Funct1()`. Both receive following a given list:

```py
Name = [‘Sai’, ‘Rusheel’,’Vinay’]

Enroll_no. = [80,90,85]

Subject = [‘Maths’, ‘Computer’, ‘Science’]
```

Both functions should form a sentence by picking elements from these lists and return them. I use for loops in `dosp_1()` and list comprehension in `disp_2()`.

Output Example:

> Sai has enrolment No. 80 and he studies Maths.

I am using the regular code as below with for loops:

```py
def Funct(Name,Enroll_No,Subject):
    for i in Name:
        for j in Enroll_No:
            for k in Subject:
                print("{} has enrolment No. {} and he studied {}".format(i,j,k))
Funct(Name,Enroll_No,Subject)
```

Now, how can I get it using list comprehension?

Comment: Please fix your code formatting.

Comment: Do you want your output to contain only three string? your current code will output 27.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by list comprehension... do you want to create a list of 3 strings like `['Sai has enrolment No. 80 and he studies Maths.', 'Rusheel has enrolemnet No. 90 and he studies Computer']` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're currently doing it, you'll print *each possible combination* of name, enroll, and subject. You probably want to print only *corresponding* combinations. The built-in `zip()` function will do this for you:

```
# as a for loop
for i, j, k in zip(Name, Enroll_No, Subject):
    print("{} has enrolment No. {} and he studied {}".format(i, j, k))

# using a comprehension
print("\n".join([
    "{} has enrolment No. {} and he studied {}".format(i, j, k)
    for (i, j, k) in zip(Name, Enroll_No, Subject)
]))

# as a for loop without using zip(), for illustration
for n in range(len(Name)):
    print(
        "{} has enrolment No. {} and he studied {}"
        .format(Name[n], Enroll_No[n], Subject[n])
    )
```

(extra line breaks added for readability)

If, for some reason, you wanted to actually print each possible combination, you can just place multiple `for` clauses inside the comprehension. This should produce identical output to your current code, but probably isn't what you want:

```
print("\n".join([
    "{} has enrolment No. {} and he studied {}".format(i, j, k)
    for i in Name
    for j in Enroll_No
    for k in Subject
]))
```

---

*technically the `[]` can be removed in this instance - a comprehension without brackets produces a *generator*, whereas a comprehension with brackets produces a *list*. For `str.join()`, both will be treated the same.